# cloning git-repository from stash via ssh

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket-server

I've got a git-repository running on a stash-server. Cloning the repository via `http` works fine

```
git clone http://user@server:7990/a/b/sandbox.git
```

For some weird reason, when I switch `http` with `ssh` and with it the port, it gives me

```
git clone ssh://user@server:7999/a/b/sandbox.git
Cloning into sandbox...
fatal: remote error: Remote URL invalid
A repository could not be determined from the remote URL. Please confirm the
clone URL in Stash and try again. URL suffix: '/scm/ct/sandbox.git'
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The server has `ssh` enabled and the port set to `7999`. How comes, that it can't find the repository when the request is sent via `ssh` rather than `http`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved. For some reason, the SSH-URL-suffix for the repository is different from the HTTP-URL-suffix. After finding that out, it worked.

Edit:
The http-url stash gave me was `user@server:7990/a/b/sandbox.git`, while the ssh-url stash gave me is `user@server:7999/b/sandbox.git` (where a and b are of course placeholders).

As it was mentioned in the comments, that I should add this to my answer.

Comment: different how? As written this isn't an answer (from the question you're better off using `~/.ssh/config` to configure ssh appropriately and just use `git clone server:path/to/repo.git`)

Comment: The http-url stash gave me was `user@server:7990/a/b/sandbox.git`, while the ssh-url stash gave me is `user@server:7999/b/sandbox.git` (where `a` and `b` are of course placeholders).

Comment: It seems like 'a/b' part change between stash and ssh this way:
in case of stash url, it is the logical path in stash. E.g. `projects/_project_/repos/_reponame_`. 
In case of ssh it has to be the usual directory path in the file system. E.g. `/dev/scm/_reponame_`

Comment: Thanks for dropping this answer here. I was just running into the same thing, instead of /a/b and just using /b it was actually /stash/scm, and I had to remove BOTH in order to get it to work right and "find" the repository.

Answer (score 1):

### Configure ssh to do it for you

Unless it's desirable to write out explicitly the clone url (e.g. cloning is performed by a parameterized script) it's generally easier to configure ssh so that it understands what `server` means and therefore the command arguments are just the defaults you'd normally expect. So for example in your [ssh config file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) put:

```
Host server
  User user
  Port 7999
```

Which then permits:

```
$ git clone server:/a/b/sandbox.git
```

In this way, and especially if there are multiple repositories on the git server, it means you don´t need to remember the more complex/explicit syntax to clone a repo.